# É errado responder uma pergunta e depois sinalizar?

Tags: suporte, sinalização

> Pergunta: [Validação de Dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194606/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados)

Quando vi esta resposta, lembrei-me de uma similar, como esta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63115/usar-js-para-aliviar-php/63700#63700), que era também principalmente baseada em opiniões, mas na altura a pergunta já contava com vários upvotes, ainda assim respondi da forma que achei conveniente,e claro, houve várias respostas boas.

O caso é que a pergunta destacada acima, tinha o mesmo padrão, mas já com 3 downvotes, e já existia uma similar. Respondi e coloquei uma referência a uma pergunta relacionada, e logo a seguir ia marcar a pergunta como "duplicada", mas em vez disso, sinalizei como "baseada em opiniões" por já possuir 4 sinalizações em pouco menos de 3 horas que era bem evidente que acabaria por ser fechada pelo mesmo motivo ainda que por outra pessoa e não creio que marcar como duplicada fosse fazer grande diferença.

Em menos de 10 minutos, recebi 2 downvotes, e a única razão que me ocorreu foi por ter sinalizado para que a pergunta fosse fechada.

Já várias vezes fiz isso, respondi a pergunta sinalizei, mas das outras vezes, fui eu o primeiro ou segundo a sinalizar contra.

Estive ausente da comunidade por cerca de ano de meio, e a menos que tenha havido mudanças na política do site em relação a casos como este, ou então sempre sempre houve uma política contra isso, *alguém me pode explicar se isto é realmente errado  e porquê ?*

Comment: Ora aqui está uma boa pergunta. Mas assim sem certezas eu diria que é, no mínimo, incongruente, visto que, se colocas uma pergunta para fechar então é porque tem problemas e, assim sendo, não deverá ser respondida. É para isso que se fecham perguntas, para que elas não sejam respondidas.

Comment: @JorgeB. certo, é de facto um bom ponto, então devo generalizar isso ?

Comment: Um problema ali (que eu fiquei em duvida do que fazer, pra falar a verdade) é quando ele pergunta da melhor linguagem. Supondo que está falando de PHP e JS só (que ao reler umas vezes parece ser o caso) realmente cabe duplicata, acho que seu entendimento do fechamento é válido. Por outro lado, duplicata com termos muito fora do contexto não ajuda a achar a original, e nesse caso o fechamento "errado" não é tão danoso assim ;)

Comment: @Bacco daí a resposta com referência da possível duplicada, porque um simples comentário não me deixaria colocar aquele texto todo *(mais para notas)* para além do link da possível duplicada.

Comment: Edilson eu entendo bem o que você fez e preciso dizer eu mesmo já fiz isto, não com o mesmo intuito que você e atuei um pouco diferente, no caso eu respondia a pergunta com o minimo de código e orientação e então eu votava para fechar como duplicata, no caso o motivo é que tem muito usuário novato e bastante teimoso que insiste em responder coisas repetidas, como se isto fosse um site de "suporte técnico", eu sempre tentava orientar para usar o sinalizar, eles prometiam fazer, mas nunca faziam, então eu comecei a responder antes deles e solicitar fechamento, isto causou uma certa...

Comment: ..."intimidação", não para o mal, mas consegui inibir certas atitudes da parte deles, ao meu ver o que você fez foi bem feito sim, não achei o downvote justo ainda mais que você atuou usando o Flag/Fechamento e apontou o link correto, na lógica claro que o correto é só "fechar", mas infelizmente tem muito caça-votos no site que insistem em responder coisas dups e fazem o conteudo bom ficar para trás, eu discuti com duas pessoas aqui no META sobre o assunto, mas acabou que infelizmente eu sai como errado e causou bastante desconforto, talvez eu tenha exagerado na discussão, mas...

Comment: ...minha motivação creio eu que era bem justa e com intenções e efeitos totalmente benéficos para a comunidade. Mas infelizmente gerou muito contra-ponto e resolvi deixar pra lá. Obs, no seu caso eu presumo que um downvote tenha sido do outro autor (que deletou a resposta), ele já entrou em alguns conflitos, mas não posso afirmar, o outro downvote deve ter sido de alguem que seguiu o primeiro, mas também não posso confirmar. No geral a sua atitude de apontar o link e atuar como atuou me parece mais benéfica do que o que os demais enxergaram. Obrigado por cuidar da comunidade =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  ao que parece, pode ser um tema algo controverso. Eu na verdade agi assim por causa de uma pergunta aqui no *meta (se não estou em erro)* que comparava o SOpt com o SOen, onde diziam que uma pergunta, ainda que duplicada, o melhor é *responder* para a criação de uma fonte alternativa e logo fechar para evitar repetições deixando o link da duplicada, como se faz naturalmente quando se fecha por duplicação. Agora que leio os vossos comentários, tenho a impressão de que talvez tenha sido em má altura apenas.

Comment: @Edilson na verdade os meus comentários são sobre isto mesmo, é o que eu apoio, responder apontando para o lugar ideal, mas ainda sim apresente algum código e de preferencia use tuas palavras, ao meu ver tua resposta me pareceu boa e apropriada. O problema é que muitos usuários não entendem os problemas que dups que demoram a ser fechadas podem causar, a sua resposta ali foi uma ótima maneira de barrar. Mas como disse os downvotes podem ter sido por outro motivo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estava algo incerto, precisava apenas de esclarecimento, porque achei que estava a ir contra regras da comunidade, acredito que se juntares estes comentários que fizeste dava aqui uma boa resposta.

Comment: Edilson irei fazer, uma pergunta é portugues ou brasileiro? A escrita as vezes soa estranho para mim e fico com receio que a maneira que escrevi possa soar estranho ou dificil de entender para ti.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não ligues para isto,sou angolano, eu entendo perfeitamente, excepto algumas palavras *(que também são pouco comuns )* e eu falo/escrevo de várias formas, dependendo do ambiente.

Comment: Então assim que tiver um tempo irei transformar em resposta os comentários. Até mais